# Collatz Conjecture; How can I edit this python code so, that it tries every number from 1 until infinity

Tags: python

This is my code that applies the conjecture to any given number:

```
def collataz(number):
    while number > 1:
        if number % 2 == 0 :
            number = number //2
            print(number)

        elif number % 2 ==1 :
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number)

        if number == 1 :
            print("DONE!")
            break


print('enter any number...!')
number=int(input())
collataz(number)
```

I want to modify it so that once its run it prints every number followed by its sequence, then moves on to the next number.

Comment: Are you asking how you can get it to prompt the user continually?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get it start from 1 without a user prompt, continuing onto 2, then 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking the user to input a number, you'd just put the call to the `collatz` function in an infinite loop.

```
number = 1
while True:
    collatz(number)
    number += 1
```

Comment: wont go to infty :) only as long as python is able to count and fit the number in its internal representation *split hairs* `print(sys.maxsize) => 9223372036854775807` - is there some kind of mathlib (numpy?) that goes beyond that threshold?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a sort of memoization to shorten the computation.  Here we record the initial number and break if the number's value is below that number, since we have already seen those results.

Then when the numbers are printed, it will return a reference to a previously printed series.  To get it to print to infinity, see @Bill-the-Lizard's answer.

```
def collataz(number):
    print(number, end=': ')
    initial_number = number
    while True:
        if number == 1 :
            print("DONE!")
            break
        if number % 2 == 0 :
            number = number //2
            if number < initial_number:
                print('[{}]'.format(number))
                break
            print(number, end=' ')

        elif number % 2 ==1 :
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number, end=' ')

# form Bill the Lizard:
n = 1
while True:
    collatz(n)
    n += 1
```

Here is the first 20 lines of this.

```
1: DONE!
2: [1]
3: 10 5 16 8 4 [2]
4: [2]
5: 16 8 [4]
6: [3]
7: 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 [5]
8: [4]
9: 28 14 [7]
10: [5]
11: 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 [10]
12: [6]
13: 40 20 [10]
14: [7]
15: 46 23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 20 [10]
16: [8]
17: 52 26 [13]
18: [9]
19: 58 29 88 44 22 [11]
20: [10]
```

Comment: this is neat - saves a lot of time as well. Needs lots of memory though if you want to keep them all in memory for "whos the longest" checking. But I guess you could only store the length information with the startnumber as key for that ... +1

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved f.e. like this: use an innner list that you fill and return it:

```
def collataz(number): 
    def collataz(number, all_nums):    
        # if you ever encounter a number that does not converge to 1 
        # you'll get no output and will miss the chance to get famous 
        # this will run till 1 then return the list. But thats what it
        # is about (the conjecture)
        while True: 
            all_nums.append(number)
            if number % 2 == 0 :
                number = number //2
            elif number % 2 ==1 :
                number = 3 * number + 1
            if number == 1:
                all_nums.append(1)
                return all_nums
    rv = [] # start with empty list and 
    collataz(number,rv) # run the inner func
    return rv # return list


print('enter any number...!')
number=int(input())
alls = collataz(number)

print(alls)
```

Output (for 678 as input):

> [678, 339, 1018, 509, 1528, 764, 382, 191, 574, 287, 862, 431, 1294, 647, 1942, 971, 2914, 1457, 4372, 2186, 1093, 3280, 1640, 820, 410, 205, 616, 308, 154, 77, 232, 116, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

You cannot run it for all numberts till infinity - reason being 
:

- limitation by usable numbers (int,long, ...) possible in python with give you a hard maximal bound of "intermediate" numbers the conjecture may be able to reach
- limitation by your lifetime - theres bound to be more numbers to check then you have nanoseconds times atoms in you
- limitation by your PCs ram, energy etc.

You can try it for many numbers:

```
aVeryHighNumber = 1000000
alltimesMax = (1,[1])
for numbr in range(2,aVeryHighNumber):
    alls = collataz(numbr) 
    print(alls)
```

You also could store the result in a dictionary but somewhen the resources of your PC will be full.

The fun part about collatz is, that the longest "row" is not nessessarily the one from the highest number. Try 837799 - wich is by some reported as longest below 1000000 starting value which is mostly of interest because of (https://projecteuler.net/problem=14)